# detect what page is loaded - ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code and some additional JS should be different for each page loaded. How can i do that? Thanks

```
  function foo(val) {
        $("#paginas").hide("fast").load(('profile' + val + '.php'), function () {

            //pseudo code
            if (page loaded is profile1)
            alert("a");

            if (page loaded is profile2)
            alert("b");

            and so on

        });
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        $('.lista' + i).bind('click', {
            button: i
        }, function (event) {
            foo(event.data.button);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to write `if (val === 2)`

Answer (score 1):

You can still access `val` from within your ajax .load() function, so you could do:

```
if(val == 'whatever') {
    //do specific thing for "whatever" page
}
```